# Changing for to while inside a nested for in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

When I try to change the nested for loop the program doesn't work as supposed

This is the original code:

```
public class AandB
{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int a = 0, b = 2;
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i>= 1; i--) {
            for(int j = 1; j <=3; j++) {
                if(j%2 == 0) {
                    b = b* 2;
                } else {
                    a= a + b;
                }

                System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b);

            } 

        }

    }
}
```

It has this output:

> a=2 b=2
>       a=2 b=4
>       a=6 b=4
>       a=10 b=4
>       a=10 b=8
>       a=18 b=8

I changed this code above so that it could work with a while loop inside the for loop:

```
public class AandB
{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int a = 0, b = 2;
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i>= 1; i--) {
            while(j <4) {
                if(j%2 == 0) {
                    b = b* 2;
                } else {
                    a= a + b;
                }

                System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b);
                j++;
            } 

        }

    }
}
```

It has this output:

> a=2 b=2
>       a=2 b=4
>       a=6 b=4
>       a=6 b=8

It should output the same results, but I can't get it right. The problem is that after the while loop ends, the for iterates but ignores the while because the condition no longer applies. I suppose I need to clear the variable j? Or create something like a counter variable?

Comment: Debug, debug, debug! Simply printing out the values of i and j at different places would have showed you where things where going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `int j = 1;` inside the `for` loop. That's the difference between your existing for loop and while loop implementations. Something like,

```
for (int i = 2; i >= 1; i--) {
    int j = 1;
    while (j < 4) {
```

When your for loop had `for(int j = 1; j <=3; j++) {` that **shadowed** the outer `j` and re-initialized to `1` on every iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

As in C/C++/Java 101, `for` is (almost) equivalent to `while` by the following conversion:

```
for (A; B; C) {
  D;
}
```

Can be written as `while` in form of:

```
A;
while(B) {
    D;
    C;
}
```

So your

```
for (int i = 2; i>= 1; i--) {
    for(int j = 1; j <=3; j++) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Should be written as (if just changing the inner loop)

```
for (int i = 2; i>= 1; i--) {
    int j = 1;
    while(j <=3) {
        // do something
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original loop, your conditional is "j <=3" in the while loop it changes to "j <=4".

Comment: Sorry, I meant j < 4.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's your initialization on the 2nd one. You're saying `while(j <=4)`, meaning that it loops 5 times, rather than on the first one, which loops 2 times.